# NavigationBar overlaps Statusbar for nested UINavigationController when hiding one navbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm running into what seems like buggy behavior. I have one UINavigationController, which contains a tabBarController within it. That tabBarController has more than 5 tabs, so there is a more button, which loads the MoreController navigationController. Of course, that creates nested navigationControllers, so I want to hide one of the navigationBars.

I do that by making my ApplicationDelegate a UINavigationControllerDelegate:

```
  [[tabBarController moreNavigationController] setDelegate:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate];
```

And implementing:

```
(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
   navigationController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

However, I end up with the Status bar overlapped:

[image: overlapped]

Now, if I add some code to fix the frame manually, there's still some weird color overlay on the status bar, and now a black gap underneath the navigation bar. What gives?

[image: still wrong]